# How to resolve "can not deserialize instance" when deserializing JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, deserialization

I have a JSON request body which looks like below

```
{
    "aaa": "value",
    "bbb": "value",
    "ccc":"value",
    "resultSuccess": {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          4.764638612000056,
          52.308615736000036
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The result field has a json value and my pojo class for this looks like

```
Class Pojo{
String aaa;
String bbb;
String ccc;
String resultSuccess;
}
```

which means i m trying to map the json that comes in result to a string value. But I get below error for this

```
  JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of 
  START_OBJECT token; nested exception is 
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize 
  instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: 
  java.io.PushbackInputStream@5b405da4;
```

I tried adding @JsonProperty("resultSuccess") but it did not work and I still get the error. Is there any way to do this without changing the datatype String?

Comment: to deserialize, I guess, property names and types should definitely match. If you want to assign an object to  a string property, you should write a Mapper method to do so.

Comment: Your claim that "the result field has a JSON value" is wrong. Firstly, there is no "result" field, but I guess you mean the "resultSuccess" field. However, that is not a string (that could contain JSON itself) but a JSON object, which is exactly what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: BTW: I just reformatted the JSON a bit and that makes it obvious that your Pojo class doesn't match the JSON structure at all!

Comment: I have modified the json as i had made a mistake.. My requirement is I cant modified my POJO to any different datatype but to keep resultSuccess as String and the value I pass to that resultSuccess filed is going to be another JSON. I cannot assign to any on object and convert it to string inside my code. I referred to this http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations and tried to using annotations like  @JsonDeserialize,    @JsonRawValue() but I still get the exception..

Comment: @gayu312 why can't you change the `Pojo` class ??? I have updated my post, and you should have those class to deserialize your JSON

Comment: I cant change my POJO because the structure has to be maintained and used by some other modules of my project

Comment: @gayu312 what structure ?? you either change the JSON or POJO, there is nothing like magic in programming.

Comment: @gayu312 please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

The error message says everything, `resultSuccess` is a Json Object not a String. You have to create the corresponding Pojo or use `JSONObject`.

Comment: My requirement is I have to read that JSON as a string. I cant change the datatype from String to any other in my POJO class. I m not aware of the annotation to read the  JSON value of resultSuccess as a string. @JsonDeserialize, @JsonRawValue()  dint help

Answer (score 0):

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT

As @zakaria mentioned, error says everything, if you look at `resultSuccess`, it is not a `String` instead an `Object`

```
"resultSuccess": {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          4.764638612000056,
          52.308615736000036
        ]
      }
    }
```

But, in your `Pojo` class, you have declared it as `String`.

```
 String resultSuccess;
```

It has to be some other type accordingly. An example could be

**Geometry.java**

```
class Geometry
{
    String type;
    double[] coordinates;
}
```

**ResultSuccess.java**

```
class ResultSuccess
{
    Geometry geometry;
}
```

**Pojo.java**

```
class Pojo
{
   String aaa;
   String bbb;
   String ccc;
   ResultSuccess resultSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way:

```
{
"aaa": "value",
"bbb": "value",
"ccc":"value",
"resultSuccess": "{
  \"geometry\": {
    \"type\": \"Point\",
    \"coordinates\": [
      4.764638612000056,
      52.308615736000036
    ]
  }
}"
}
```

other way make resultSuccess be a pojo

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Conert Json to Java Pojo Class](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to get `pojo` class of your `json`.